# javascript textarea value with new line from database

Tags: javascript

Below there is a script which adds a signature in a textarea field. The signature comes from a database table and it is a text column. Also, before adding it into the text area, it adds two new lines in front to give space for writing.

```
$value = '\n\n'.$signature['usertext'];                     
<script type="text/javascript">
    var signature = "$value";
    var ta = document.getElementById('emailbox');
    ta.value = signature;
</script>
```

The problem comes when the signature added in the database is more than one lines. It simply doesn't get added into the textarea. The value of the usertext column is this:

```
test550550

adsadasdasdas
```

Any help would be thanked.

Comment: how does the database store new lines in the field?

Comment: is `$value = '\n\n'.$signature['usertext'];` PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

Is it javascript or php? i think javascript use "+" instead of "." for string concatenation.  So your `$value = '\n\n'.$signature['usertext'];`  might need to be changed to `$value = '\n\n' + $signature['usertext'];`